# Makefile Error : Command Not Found- while creating a shared library

Tags: c, linux, makefile, shared-libraries

I have 4 .c files `hello.c`,`here.c`,`bye.c` and `main.c`.
One header file `mylib.h`

The contents are as follows

hello.c

```
#include<stdio.h>

void hello()
{
    printf("Hello!\n");
}
```

here.c

```
#include<stdio.h>

void here()
{
     printf("I am here \n");
}
```

bye.c

```
#include<stdio.h>

void bye()
{
    printf("Bye,Bye");
}
```

main.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include "mylib.h"

int main()
{ 

  hello();
  here();
  bye();
  return 1;
}
```

mylib.h

```
#ifndef _mylib_
#define _mylib_

void hello();
void here();
void bye();

#endif
```

The makefile for creating a static lib is :
Makefile

```
#Which Compiler
CC = gcc

#Compiler Flags
CFLAGS = - Wall -c -fPIC

DYNLINKFLAGS = -shared -W1,-soname,$@.0

PROG = main

PROG_OBJS = main.c

LIB = mylib

LIB_FILES = libmylib.so

LIB_MINOR = $(LIB_FILES).0.1

LIB_RELEASE = $(LIB_MINOR).0

LIB_OBJS = hello.o here.o bye.o

PATH = /home/srinivasa/cspp51081/labs/srinivasa.lab2.1

all:    $(LIB_FILES) $(PROG)

#Create Lib with this file
$(LIB_FILES):   $(LIB_OBJS)
            $(CC) $(DYNLINKFLAGS) $^
            ln -sf $(LIB_RELEASE) $(LIB_MINOR)
            ln -sf $(LIB_MINOR) $@
            ln -sf $@ $@.0

#Compiling main program and link with shared library
$(PROG):        $(PROG_OBJS)
            $(CC) -o $(PROG) $(PORG_OBJS) -l$(LIB) -L$(PATH)

main.o:         main.c
hello.o:        hello.c
here.o:         here.c
bye.o:          bye.c

#clean files
clean:
            rm -rf $(LIB_OBJS) $(LIB_FILES) $(LIB_RELEASE) $(LIB_MINOR) libmylib.so.0
```

Problem: When I execute the command

```
make -f Makefile all
```

I get the error:

gcc -Wall -fPIC   -c -o hello.o hello.c
make: gcc: Command not found
make: *** [hello.o] Error 127

Questions : `How do I resolve this?`

Comment: Are you sure that you have the file main.c in the same directory where you are running the make command?

Comment: @Ziffusion - THanks for the insightful comment. I believe somewhere the main.c file had been deleted. I now have written a new main.c and put in the folder. However now I get 'gcc -Wall -fPIC   -c -o hello.o hello.c
make: gcc: Command not found
make: *** [hello.o] Error 127'

Comment: Any chance you can post debug make output?

Comment: That's because you are setting the value of PATH in your Makefile. The shell is unable to find gcc because of that. Try renaming the PATH variable in the Makefile to, say, LIBPATH (in all places).

Comment: @Ziffusion: +1 . Thanks, no way that I would have figured that out. Now I get the error - /usr/bin/ld: `cannot find -lmylib
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [main] Error 1` Not sure as to why linker is not able to find the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

+++++

OK. Lets revert to your original code, but with a small difference.

Change DYNLINKFLAGS back to:

```
DYNLINKFLAGS = -shared -Wl,-soname,$@.0
```

Then change the library link to:

```
$(CC) $(DYNLINKFLAGS) -o $(LIB_RELEASE) $^
ln -sf $(LIB_RELEASE) $(LIB_MINOR)
ln -sf $(LIB_MINOR) $@
ln -sf $@ $@.0
```

Do "rm -f lib*", build and then post make output.

Comment: I guess this works :). Make output 
gcc -Wall -c -fPIC   -c -o hello.o hello.c
gcc -Wall -c -fPIC   -c -o here.o here.c
gcc -Wall -c -fPIC   -c -o bye.o bye.c
gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,libmylib.so.0  -o libmylib.so.0.1 hello.o here.o bye.o
ln -sf libmylib.so.0.1 libmylib.so.0.1.0
ln -sf libmylib.so.0.1.0 libmylib.so
gcc -Wl,-Bdynamic -o main main.c -L/home/srinivasa/cspp51081/labs/srinivasa.lab2.1 -lmylib

Comment: Well, there you go. Wasn't that easy :)

Comment: Thanks for all the help and time. Now to see the output I did the following 1. Set Library Path: export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/srinivasa/cspp51081/labs/srinivasa.lab2.1
2. Recompile 3. ldd main - I see that  the main cannot find the shared library ldd main    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff89ef2000)
  libmylib.so.0 => not found
  libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007f1d4d94d000)
  /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f1d4dca1000)

Comment: I am not sure I got this. This is happening when you run the executable? Which shared library is it unable to find?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few bugs (just typos) I can see is:

1. space between `-` and `Wall`:

   ```
   CFLAGS = - Wall -c -fPIC
             ^
   ```
2. `PORG_OBJS` should be `PROG_OBJS`

   ```
   $(CC) -o $(PROG) $(PORG_OBJS) -L$(PATH)
                      ^^^^
   ```
3. You are doing an absolute assignment to `PATH`. Now every executable called in makefile will be search in that directory. Since `gcc` is not found in that directory you get this error. To fix this you can either use a *different* variable name or add your directory to current path as:

   ```
    PATH := $(PATH):/home/srinivasa/cspp51081/labs/srinivasa.lab2.1
         ^  ^^^^^^^^
   ```

Comment: thanks , changed the question. Hope you can view it what the change was.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this line from:

```
$(CC) -o $(PROG) $(PORG_OBJS) -l$(LIB) -L$(LIBPATH)
```

to:

```
$(CC) -o $(PROG) $(PORG_OBJS) -L$(LIBPATH) -l$(LIB)
```

The -L flag needs to precede the -l flags.

Comment: @Ziffusion - Changed it . get the same error gcc -o main main.c -L/home/srinivasa/cspp51081/labs/srinivasa.lab2.1 -lmylib
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmylib
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [main] Error 1

Comment: Well, first check the directory to see which library files are being produced. Next, try passing "-dynamic" flag to the compiler. Then post the entire make output (including the library build, and the executable build).

Comment: Oh, and I see that you are using DYNLINKFLAGS, but you don't ever define it. Chances are that you are actually producing a static library, even though it has the ".so" suffix.

Comment: @Ziffusion: Libraries being created 

`libmylib.so.0 -> libmylib.so
libmylib.so -> libmylib.so.0.1
libmylib.so.0.1 -> libmylib.so.0.1.0`

Comment: @Ziffusion - 
make output:
`
gcc -Wall -c -fPIC   -c -o hello.o hello.c
gcc -Wall -c -fPIC   -c -o here.o here.c
gcc -Wall -c -fPIC   -c -o bye.o bye.c
gcc -dynamic -shared -W1,-soname,libmylib.so.0 hello.o here.o bye.o
ln -sf libmylib.so.0.1.0 libmylib.so.0.1
ln -sf libmylib.so.0.1 libmylib.so
ln -sf libmylib.so libmylib.so.0
gcc -o main main.c -L/home/srinivasa/cspp51081/labs/srinivasa.lab2.1 -lmylib
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmylib
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [main] Error 1`

Comment: @Ziffusion - I do use the DYNLINKFLAGS - this line 
$(LIB_FILES):   $(LIB_OBJS)
            $(CC) $(DYNLINKFLAGS) $^

Comment: The library naming and linking seems a little off. You link the objects into a shared library called "libmylib.so.0", then one of your soft links go "ln -sf libmylib.so libmylib.so.0". That doesn't seem right. One thing you need to fix is get the order of links light. I would just link from the real library i.e. "libmylib.so.0" to all other names. After, post the libraries produced and the final link again.

Comment: @ Ziffusion - Changed the order of links . Now I create a soft link from the real library 
                $(CC) $(DYNLINKFLAGS) $^
                ln -sf $(LIB_RELEASE) $(LIB_FILES)
                ln -sf $(LIB_RELEASE) $(LIB_FILES).1

Comment: @Ziffusion - make output 
gcc -Wall -c -fPIC   -c -o hello.o hello.c
gcc -Wall -c -fPIC   -c -o here.o here.c
gcc -Wall -c -fPIC   -c -o bye.o bye.c
gcc -dynamic -shared -W1,-soname,libmylib.so.0 hello.o here.o bye.o
ln -sf libmylib.so.0.1.0 libmylib.so
ln -sf libmylib.so.0.1.0 libmylib.so.1
gcc -o main main.c -L/home/srinivasa/cspp51081/labs/srinivasa.lab2.1 -lmylib
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmylib
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [main] Error 1

Comment: But that's still not right. The real linked library is "libmylib.so.0". And you are linking "libmylib.so.0.1.0" to other names.

Comment: @Ziffusion- Ohh, now I am a little confused about the order of linking files. Could you kindly write down the order of creating the softlinks.

Comment: @Ziffusion - I have changed the ordering now. It is 
ln -sf libmylib.so.0 libmylib.so.0.1
ln -sf libmylib.so.0 libmylib.so.0.1.0

Comment: @Ziffusion - now the make output reads gcc -Wall -c -fPIC   -c -o hello.o hello.c
gcc -Wall -c -fPIC   -c -o here.o here.c
gcc -Wall -c -fPIC   -c -o bye.o bye.c
gcc -dynamic -shared -W1,-soname,libmylib.so.0 hello.o here.o bye.o
ln -sf libmylib.so.0 libmylib.so.0.1
ln -sf libmylib.so.0 libmylib.so.0.1.0
gcc -o main main.c -L/home/srinivasa/cspp51081/labs/srinivasa.lab2.1 -lmylib
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmylib
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [main] Error 1

Comment: You didn't do exactly what I asked you to :) You did not change DYNLINKFLAGS. And you didn't fix the links like I asked.

Answer (score 0):

OK. First change:

```
DYNLINKFLAGS = -shared -W1,-soname,$@.0
```

to

```
DYNLINKFLAGS = -shared -W1,-soname,$@
```

Then change:

```
ln -sf $(LIB_RELEASE) $(LIB_MINOR)
ln -sf $(LIB_MINOR) $@
ln -sf $@ $@.0
```

To:

```
ln -sf $@ $(LIB_RELEASE)
ln -sf $@ $(LIB_MINOR)
ln -sf $@ $@.0
```

Then post the library links and the final executable link.

Comment: make output :gcc -Wall -c -fPIC   -c -o hello.o hello.c
gcc -Wall -c -fPIC   -c -o here.o here.c
gcc -Wall -c -fPIC   -c -o bye.o bye.c
gcc -dynamic -shared -W1,-soname,libmylib.so hello.o here.o bye.o
ln -sf libmylib.so libmylib.so.0.1.0
ln -sf libmylib.so libmylib.so.0.1
ln -sf libmylib.so libmylib.so.0
gcc -o main main.c -L/home/srinivasa/cspp51081/labs/srinivasa.lab2.1 -lmylib
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmylib
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [main] Error 1

Comment: library links : 
libmylib.so.0 -> libmylib.so
libmylib.so.0.1 -> libmylib.so
libmylib.so.0.1.0 -> libmylib.so

Comment: Now add "-dynamic" to the final link of the executable. Then post the make output.

Comment: gcc -Wall -c -fPIC   -c -o hello.o hello.c
gcc -Wall -c -fPIC   -c -o here.o here.c
gcc -Wall -c -fPIC   -c -o bye.o bye.c
gcc -dynamic -shared -W1,-soname,libmylib.so hello.o here.o bye.o
ln -sf libmylib.so libmylib.so.0.1.0
ln -sf libmylib.so libmylib.so.0.1
ln -sf libmylib.so libmylib.so.0
gcc -dynamic -o main main.c -L/home/srinivasa/cspp51081/labs/srinivasa.lab2.1 -lmylib
main.c:1: warning: The C parser does not support -dy, option ignored
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmylib
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [main] Error 1
Hope the -dynamic flag is in correct place

Comment: Now replace "-dynamic" by "-Wl,-Bdynamic" (only in the final executable link). And post the make output.

Comment: gcc -Wall -c -fPIC   -c -o hello.o hello.c
gcc -Wall -c -fPIC   -c -o here.o here.c
gcc -Wall -c -fPIC   -c -o bye.o bye.c
gcc -dynamic -shared -W1,-soname,libmylib.so hello.o here.o bye.o
ln -sf libmylib.so libmylib.so.0.1.0
ln -sf libmylib.so libmylib.so.0.1
ln -sf libmylib.so libmylib.so.0
gcc -Wl,-Bdynamic -o main main.c -L/home/srinivasa/cspp51081/labs/srinivasa.lab2.1 -lmylib
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmylib
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [main] Error 1

Comment: Strange. Can you do "objdump libmylib.so"?

Comment: And try moving "-Wl,-Bdynamic" right in front of "-lmylib". Otherwise I am out of ideas for now. Maybe someone else can pick this up. Or we could try it again tomorrow.

Comment: @Ziffusion - Thanks for all your help. We can definitely carry on tomorrow , idf you wish. Ill do a objdump and post it.

Comment: Are you sure you are cleaning out the old links before each build? Just do a "rm -f lib*", and build again.

Comment: @Ziffusion -  objdump -f libmylib.so
objdump: 'libmylib.so': No such file

Comment: That's what I thought. Try cleaning the libs before building. Do the "rm -f lib*" and build again.

Comment: BTW I just noticed, in the definition of DYNLINKFLAGS "-W1,-soname,libmylib.so" - that looks like a "1 (one)" instead of an "l (el)". That should be an "l (el)".

Comment: No Luck - I get the same error gcc -Wall -c -fPIC   -c -o hello.o hello.c
gcc -Wall -c -fPIC   -c -o here.o here.c
gcc -Wall -c -fPIC   -c -o bye.o bye.c
gcc -dynamic -shared -W1,-soname,libmylib.so hello.o here.o bye.o
ln -sf libmylib.so libmylib.so.0.1.0
ln -sf libmylib.so libmylib.so.0.1
ln -sf libmylib.so libmylib.so.0
gcc -Wl,-Bdynamic -o main main.c -L/home/srinivasa/cspp51081/labs/srinivasa.lab2.1 -lmylib
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmylib
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [main] Error 1
 objdump -f libmylib.so
objdump: 'libmylib.so': No such file

Comment: See last comment. Repeat - BTW I just noticed, in the definition of DYNLINKFLAGS "-W1,-soname,libmylib.so" - that looks like a "1 (one)" instead of an "l (el)". That should be an "l (el)".

Comment: @Ziffusion - Changed the 1(one) to l(el) - no change in output

Comment: @Ziffusion -Sry,but I dint get what you mean by "+++++"

Comment: I posted another answer (better formatting) and marked it with a line "+++++" on the top.